# Android GridView within Fragment is not populated on app startup but works after rotate

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am trying to follow the Udacity Developing Android Apps course and I stepped into this strange behaviour of which I cannot find the root cause.

Basically I have a fragment within an activity with a GridView inside. The GridView must be dynamically populated with the data coming from "The Movie Database", particularly I would like to have a series of ImageView containing a movie poster inside my GridView. What happens is that on the application startup the GridView is not populated, but when I change the orientation of the phone (or even move to another Activity and come back to the initial Activity) I can see the movie images being loaded and displayed in the GridView.

Any ideas why is that so?

I hereby put the code of my layouts and source files.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SummaryFragment.java

```
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String LOG_CAT = SummaryFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private GridView gridView;

public SummaryFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateMovies();
}

private void updateMovies() {
    FetchMovieTask fetchMovieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
    fetchMovieTask.execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    return rootView;
}

private class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Movie[]> {

    private static final String SCHEME = "http";
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "api.themoviedb.org";
    private static final String AUTHORITY_IMAGE = "image.tmdb.org";
    private static final String VERSION = "3";
    private static final String MOVIE = "movie";
    private static final String API_KEY = "api_key";
    private static final String T = "t";
    private static final String P = "p";
    private static final String DIM = "w500";

    @Override
    protected Movie[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultFromFetch = null;

        try {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            String filter = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.preference_sorting_key),
                    getString(R.string.preference_sorting_default));

            Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme(SCHEME)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY)
                    .appendPath(VERSION)
                    .appendPath(MOVIE)
                    .appendPath(filter)
                    .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY, BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY)
                    .build();

            String formattedURI = uri.toString();

            URL url = new URL(formattedURI);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if (is == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            if (sb.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            resultFromFetch = sb.toString();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return parseResponse(resultFromFetch);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_CAT, "JSON not well formatted", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Movie[] parseResponse(String resultFromFetch) throws JSONException {
        final String RESULTS = "results";
        final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
        final String ID = "id";
        final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE = "original_language";
        final String TITLE = "title";
        final String BACKDROP_PATH = "backdrop_path";
        final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
        final String VOTE_COUNT = "vote_count";

        JSONObject fetchResult = new JSONObject(resultFromFetch);
        JSONArray results = fetchResult.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

        Movie[] arrayOfMovies = new Movie[results.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfMovies.length; ++i) {
            JSONObject movieToParse = results.getJSONObject(i);


            String overview = movieToParse.getString(OVERVIEW);
            int id = movieToParse.getInt(ID);
            String originalTitle = movieToParse.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
            String originalLanguage = movieToParse.getString(ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE);
            String title = movieToParse.getString(TITLE);

            double voteAverage = movieToParse.getDouble(VOTE_AVERAGE);
            int voteCount = movieToParse.getInt(VOTE_COUNT);

            Uri uriBackdrop = new Uri.Builder().scheme(SCHEME)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY_IMAGE)
                    .appendPath(T)
                    .appendPath(P)
                    .appendPath(DIM)
                    .appendEncodedPath(movieToParse.getString(BACKDROP_PATH))
                    .build();
            String backdropPath = uriBackdrop.toString();

            Uri uriPoster = new Uri.Builder().scheme(SCHEME)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY_IMAGE)
                    .appendPath(T)
                    .appendPath(P)
                    .appendPath(DIM)
                    .appendEncodedPath(movieToParse.getString(POSTER_PATH))
                    .build();
            String posterPath = uriPoster.toString();
            arrayOfMovies[i] = new Movie(title,
                                        originalTitle,
                                        originalLanguage,
                                        overview,
                                        posterPath,
                                        backdropPath,
                                        id,
                                        voteCount,
                                        voteAverage);

        }

        return arrayOfMovies;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Movie[] movies) {
        if (movies != null) {
            MovieArrayAdapter movieArrayAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                    Arrays.asList(movies));

            gridView.setAdapter(movieArrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Movie.java

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

private int id;
private String backdrop_path;
private String original_language;
private String original_title;
private String overview;
private String poster_path;
private String title;
private double vote_average;
private int vote_count;


public Movie(String title,
             String original_title,
             String original_language,
             String overview,
             String poster_path,
             String backdrop_path,
             int id,
             int vote_count,
             double vote_average) {
    this.title = title;
    this.original_language = original_language;
    this.original_title = original_title;
    this.poster_path = poster_path;
    this.overview = overview;
    this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    this.id =id;
    this.vote_average = vote_average;
    this.vote_count = vote_count;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(id);
    out.writeInt(vote_count);
    out.writeDouble(vote_average);
    out.writeString(backdrop_path);
    out.writeString(original_language);
    out.writeString(original_title);
    out.writeString(overview);
    out.writeString(poster_path);
    out.writeString(title);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
    public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movie(in);
    }

    public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
    }
};

public int getVote_count() {
    return vote_count;
}

public double getVote_average() {
    return vote_average;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getBackdrop_path() {
    return backdrop_path;
}

public String getOriginal_title() {
    return original_title;
}

public String getOriginal_language() {
    return original_language;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}

public String getPoster_path() {
    return poster_path;
}

private Movie(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    vote_count = in.readInt();

    vote_average = in.readDouble();
    backdrop_path = in.readString();
    original_language = in.readString();
    original_title = in.readString();
    overview = in.readString();
    poster_path = in.readString();
    title = in.readString();
}
}
```

MovieArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

private Context context;

private static final String LOG_CAT = MovieArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public MovieArrayAdapter(Context context,  List<Movie> movies) {
    super(context,0,movies);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View viewLayout, ViewGroup parent) {
    Movie movieItem = getItem(position);

    if (viewLayout == null) {
        viewLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, parent, false);
        Log.d(LOG_CAT, "View not existent. Creating it...");
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_CAT, "Recycling view...");
    }

    Picasso.with(context).load(movieItem.getBackdrop_path()).into((ImageView)viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SummaryFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

my_image_view.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/image_view_thumbnail"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

content_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.paxilpaz.movieapp.SummaryFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: when do you create the fragment?

Comment: Hi Lino, I forgot to append the code handling the creation of the fragment. I will update the question with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to setAdapter onCreateView, instead of onPostExecute.

Set the adapter first, even if you don't have any data yet, just pass an empty array, but then onPostExecute update the adapter so it updates the view.

For example, onCreateView:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main);
        myMoviesAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this.getActivity(), myMovies);
        // Set the adapter on the GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);
```

Then, onPostExecute:

```
 movieAdapter.clear();
 for (Movie record : myMovies) {
     movieAdapter.add(record);
}
```